# Google Sheets connecting with Gmail or Slack

Tags: google-sheets, encoding, gmail, slack, drive

I'm looking for a code I can use in google sheets.
I need to get a notification when a cell changes in a specific column and get it through email or Slack.
Can someone please help me?
I'm currently using

```js
function onSpeEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = e.source.getActiveRange();
  var col = 1
  if (sh.getName() == 'mySheet' && rng.getColumn() == col) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      'yourEmail@gmail.com',
      `Change Notification`,
      `Change in ${rng.getA1Notation()} old value "${e.oldValue}" new value "${e.value}" `);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack we are not a coding service.   Please edit your question and show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function onSpeEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = e.source.getActiveRange();
  var col = 1
  if (rng.getColumn() == col) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      'yourEmail@gmail.com',
      `Change Notification`,
      `Change in ${rng.getA1Notation()} of ${sh.getName()} old value "${e.oldValue}" new value "${e.value}" `);
  }
}
```

change **name** of sheet, **column** and **email** address

you will need to define an installable **trigger** in order to use services that requires authorization.

[Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

edit : il you want to add another information, i.e. from column B, try to replace the sentence by

```
`Hey, the title ${sh.getRange('B'+rng.getRow()).getValue()} from sheet ${sh.getName()} changed. Before it has the number ${e.oldValue} now is ${e.value}.`
```

Comment: Excuse me sir, this pops up when I try to use that code "TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
onSpeEdit @ Código.gs:2" What can I do?

Comment: you should not launch this script when you are in the script editor, this script will be automatically launched when you manually modify a cell in the column concerned. Previously you need to put an installable trigger on the function.

Comment: One last question - or not - when modifying the cell, I receive this email "Change in A201 old value "undefined" new value "undefined""
Why is it "undefined" if I literally writing words?

Comment: do you change only one cell or a group of cells ?

Comment: only one cell :(

Comment: weird! I test one more time on my side and get `Change in A1 old value "abcd" new value "xyz"` can you share a very light spreadsheet with code?

Comment: Hi Mike! I tested one again and it's working now!!
However, how can I apply this code to all the sheets rather just one?

Comment: remove `sh.getName() == 'mySheet' &&`

Comment: Hi Mike! I need one more tip. With this code I get what changed but I would like get notify from which sheet it's the cell that changed.

Comment: add ${sh.getName()} , done in the updated answer

Comment: Hi Mike, this doesn't work because I'm not using `if (sh.getName() == 'mySheet' && rng.getColumn() == col) {` because I have multiple sheets in the same google sheets

Comment: I'm using  if (rng.getColumn() == col) {

Comment: done! 
However I'm still having issues cause. what should I change from this code?
`function onSpeEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = e.source.getActiveRange();
  var col = 1
  if (rng.getColumn() == col) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      'xxx@gmail.com',
      `Cambio DSID`,
      `Cambio en la celda ${rng.getA1Notation()} antes era "${e.oldValue}" ahora es "${e.value}" `);
  }
}`

Comment: What should I change because I would like to know from what sheet is the cell that changed

Comment: i have updated my answer, tell me if it is ok, you will just have to translate

Comment: Hi Mike - AGAIN. Firstly, thank you so much for your help and patience. I'm trying to improve the code as I find new information I can add. Let me explain, I have different titles in column B and numbers in column F. As for now, the code comes back as what changes in column F and from which sheet it is, but I would like it to be something like "Hey, the title X (column B) from sheet X changed. Before it has the number XXX now is ZZZ. How can I add the column B part?

Comment: Hi Naiara, added as edit in the answer.

Comment: `Oye, el título ${sh.getRange('B'+rng.getRow()).getValue()} de la hoja ${sh.getName()} cambió. Antes tenía el número ${e.oldValue} ahora es ${e.value}.`

Comment: you need to put this between 2 grave accents