# Get a slack notification when spreadsheets changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, slack

I would like to get a notification in my slack when a cell changes in column G in all the sheets from a document I have in google sheets. I currently have this code where I get an email. If I can keep gmail + slack notification would be awesome.

```
function onSpeEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = e.source.getActiveRange();
  var col = 7
  if (rng.getColumn() == col) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      'xxxx@gmail.com',
      `Cambio DSID`,
      `Cambio en la celda ${rng.getA1Notation()} antes era "${e.oldValue}" ahora es "${e.value}" `);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you have tried to get the notification in Slack and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: This is question repost: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73172284/1595451. If you question was closed, instead of reposting it edit the original question to make it a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to [create a custom app in Slack](https://api.slack.com/)

Try

```
function onSpeEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = e.source.getActiveRange();
  var col = 7
  if (rng.getColumn() == col) {

    // email
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      'xxxx@gmail.com',
      `Cambio DSID`,
      `Cambio en la celda '${sh.getName()}'!${rng.getA1Notation()} antes era "${e.oldValue}" ahora es "${e.value}" `);

    // slack
    let message = {
      "blocks": [
        {
          "type": "section",
          "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "Cambio DSID"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "divider"
        },
        {
          "type": "section",
          "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": `Cambio en la celda '${sh.getName()}'!${rng.getA1Notation()} `
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "section",
          "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": `antes era "${e.oldValue}" `
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "section",
          "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": `ahora es "${e.value}" `
          }
        }
      ]
    };
    const webhook = ""; //Paste your webhook URL here
    sendSlackAlert(webhook, message)

  }
}
function sendSlackAlert(webhook, payload) {
  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  try {
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(webhook, options);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: to create a custom app in Slack : https://www.august.com.au/blog/how-to-send-slack-alerts-from-google-sheets-apps-script/#step1

Comment: I added the name of sheet in the answer, please check and give a feed-back